# Dark mode in NextJS and React, reloads the app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, darkmode

I implemented a simple dark mode in Next, using React and Mui.

The toggle is in the navbar of the website, but if I navigate around, and then press the toggle for Dark Mode, the app reloads back to localhost, instead of retaining the URL I was visiting.

This is the code I am using on the entry point level.

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [splash, setSplash] = useState(true);

  const [mode, setMode] = useState<PaletteMode>('light');
  const colorMode = useMemo(
    () => ({
      // The dark mode switch would invoke this method
      toggleColorMode: () => {
        setMode((prevMode: PaletteMode) => (prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'));
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  // Update the theme only if the mode changes
  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(getDesignTokens(mode)), [mode]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post('/api/http/identities/link', {})
      .then(() => setLoading(false))
      .catch(() => {
        setLoading(false);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSplash(false);
        }, 1000);
      });

    return () => {};
  }, []);

  return splash ? (
    <SplashPage triggerFade={splash} />
  ) : (
    <UserProvider>
      <Global
        styles={css`
          html,
          body,
          body > div:first-of-type,
          div#__next,
          div#__next > div {
            height: 100%;
          }

          body {
            margin: 0;
          }
        `}
      />{' '}
      <Head>
        <title>{getTabName(router)}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
      </Head>
      <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />

          <div suppressHydrationWarning>
          <The rest of my app here/>
          </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </ColorModeContext.Provider>
    </UserProvider>
  );
};

export const DarkModeToggle = () => {
  const colorMode = useContext(ColorModeContext);
  const [darkModeOn, setDarkModeOn] = useState(false);

  const handleToggleMode = () => {
    setDarkModeOn(prevMode => !prevMode);
    colorMode.toggleColorMode();
  };

  return (
    <IconButton sx={{ ml: 1 }} onClick={handleToggleMode} color="inherit">
      {darkModeOn ? <Brightness7Icon /> : <Brightness4Icon />}
    </IconButton>
  );
};
```

Do you know how can I avoid the page refresh and retain the URL navigation upon switching modes?

Thank you!